# も and the double を in それこそ ハイエロファントグリーンを使えば苦痛を感じる間もあたえず一瞬のうちに

Tags: grammar, meaning, particles

> それこそ ハイエロファントグリーンを使えば苦痛を感じる間もあたえず一瞬のうちに。

My translation:

> If I used Hierophant Green, pain would not last more than a moment.

The context is: a character wondering about another one sleeping near him after they fought each other and he wanted to kill him, but the other not only stopped him, but saved his life too. Now he's thinking how much easy would be to kill him with his own power.

I'm not sure about that も and the double を. And: あたえず is negative?

Answer (score 3):

> 「それこそ ハイエロファントグリーンを[使]{つか}えば[苦痛]{くつう}を[感]{かん}じる[間]{ま}もあたえず[一瞬]{いっしゅん}のうちに。」

To add punctuation for (hopefully) better understanding.

> 「それこそ、ハイエロファントグリーンを使えば、苦痛を感じる間もあたえず、一瞬のうちに。」

The most important point for a Japanese learner would be to notice that **a whole verb phrase is left unmentioned** at the end of the sentence.  From the way you worded your question, I could not tell if you noticed it.

***It is important because that is the main verb of the sentence.***

"One does something", "Something happens", etc. in just a second (一瞬のうちに). What that thing is is "omitted".

No translation attempt would be good enough without correctly "guessing" what the omitted part would be saying.  In your case, you actually mentioned the verb phrase around the middle part of your question.  ***It is "to kill the other guy".***  That is what will happen in just a second.

> "Surely, if I used Hierophant Green, I could kill him in a split second without even giving him any time to feel pain."

「も」 means "even" here, which I used in my TL.

The double 「を」 are necessary.  "feel pain" and "use H. Green".

「あたえず」 is negative.  "without giving him ~~"